# MongoDB & PHP - How do I exclude results from a date range delimited query?

Tags: php, mongodb, find

Long time peruser, first time question asker ...

Using PHP to query our MongoDB page visit log, I would like to get a set of records between two time periods, but exclude results that have a certain userAgent.  I've figured out the time range but cannot find anywhere that explains the exclude.

Here's what I have for the query so far:

```
$dateRange = $collection->find(array("timeStamp" => array('$gt' => $start, 
                                                          '$lt' => $end)));
```

Looking for code to complete the find function to exclude the records with a "userAgent" starting with "ELB"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is $ne or $nin, depending on whether the value you want to exclude is a single value or array of values. eg:

```
$dateRange = $collection->find(array("timeStamp" => array('$gt' => $start, '$lt' => end), 'userAgent' => array('$ne' => new MongoRegex('/^ELB/'))));
```

Documentation here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24ne
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin

Comment: This worked, thank you!  I had to ditch the regex though ... $dateRange = $collection->find(array(
    'timeStamp' => array(
        '$gt' => $start,
        '$lt' => $end
    ),
    'userAgent' => array(
        '$ne' => 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0'
    )
));

Answer (score 1):

You could append `{$not: /^ELB/}` to the mongo query.

Not really sure about the equivalent PHP but try something like this:

```
$dateRange = $collection->find(array(
    'timeStamp' => array(
        '$gt' => $start,
        '$lt' => $end
    ),
    'userAgent' => array(
        '$not' => new MongoRegex('/^ELB/')
    )
));
```

Comment: Except for the regex, this worked!  Thank you!  I changed $not to $ne as well: $dateRange = $collection->find(array(
    'timeStamp' => array(
        '$gt' => $start,
        '$lt' => $end
    ),
    'userAgent' => array(
        '$ne' => 'ELB-HealthChecker/1.0'
    )
));

Comment: Great, I used a regexp since you wanted to match "starting with ELB". And don't forget to accept an answer ;)